# Why doesn't a call to DbMigration.Sql with invalid sql throw an error?

Tags: entity-framework-migrations

I have the following initial migration script.

The code in the #region up was created by Entity Framework.

However I don't want the initial migration to run if the _MigrationHistory table already exists.

I was surprised to find that DbMigration.Sql swallows the error that should occur if the table does not exist.

```
public partial class startup : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {

        try
        {
            Sql("select top 1 MigrationId from __MigrationHistory");
            return;

        }
        catch
        {
            //
        }


        #region up   // should run if the sql() call fails

         CreateTable(
            "dbo.ConfigurationNumbers",
            c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 60),
                Value = c.String(nullable: false),
                Prefix = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 20),
            })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        // etc
        #endregion
  }
```

Given that the table does not exist, why doesn't the call to sql() raise an error ?

I have since got the Up() method to work as I want as follows
        public override void Up()
        {
            if (HandyDatabase.TableExists("ConfigurationNumbers"))

```
        {
            return;
        }


        #region up
        etc
```

with

```
 public static class HandyDatabase
 {
    public static bool TableExists(string tableName )
    {
        using (var connect = new JobTalkDbContext())
        {
            var results = connect.Database.SqlQuery<string>(@"SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_name = @param1", new SqlParameter("param1", tableName)).ToArray();
            var result = results.FirstOrDefault();
            return result != null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to manually create __MigrationHistory? That table is created automatically by Entity Framework.

Comment: Odd. I never have to deal with the __MigrationHistory. EF just handles it behind the scenes - nothing in my up code. When I script out the actual SQL Server code it does check for existence at the top and create the table if it does not exist. Try `update-database -SourceMigration 0 -Script` and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks @SteveGreene  I have since removed the call to create __MigrationHistory , and it turns out my use case does not need it. Nor does my question.

Perhaps I should look at the EntityFramework code to find out why the error is swallowed?  It seems like a poor decision.

Comment: I always try to keep in mind this is intermediate code used to produce database code for potentially different providers. There are lots of gotchas.